# Invalid Resource File Directory in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-studio

The entire code has compiled perfectly but I am getting an error of invalid resource directory name.

The exact error is :

> C:\Users\DELL\Documents\Projects\PhoneWord\PhoneWord\aapt.exe: Error: Invalid resource directory name: "res aboutresources.txt". (PhoneWord)

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please share your project hierarchy?

Comment: I think this is due to "res aboutresources.txt" this should be "res\aboutresources.txt" I think. if you are referenceing it some where in code then you should try "res\\aboutresources.txt"

Answer (score 8):

My AboutResources.txt (or whatever file is mentioned in the error) had its build action accidentally set to AndroidResource. I changed its build action back to "None" and recompiled, the error was fixed.

Comment: After I changed that to `None` then its throwing another error

Comment: do as he says then delete bin and obj folder. clean build and it works. i just had the sam error as you desribed but that fixt that

Answer (score 3):

Following solved the problem for me.

1. Right click **AboutResource.txt** file.
2. Click Properties
3. Change **Build Action** to **None**

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Did you set the build actions as "EmbeddedResource" in resouce(file) properties window?
2. Can you try to understand the code below.

## region How to load a text file embedded resource

```
        var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt");

        string text = "";
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream)) {
            text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: How do i set the build actions as "EmbeddedResouce"?

Comment: You can do it in two ways
1. Right click on the resource > Build Actions > Embedded Resource
2. Open Properties window for Resource and In "Build Resource" Property choose "Embedded Resource".

Answer (score 1):

I had 2 things that worked for me:

1.
(it's only a temporary fix)
I renamed the "Recources" folder to "recources" problem then was that the design preview throw an exception (Visual Studio 2015 + xamarin add on) but i could release it. After that i renamed it to "Recources" and i could change it, then back to "recources" and so on

2.
What solved all my problems (i had severals more), was to create a new Project and copy-paste all the previous stuff. Everything worked fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

save a copy of AboutResources.txt to any directory or folder. delete the AboutResources.txt in resources folder from the visual studio, then copy back the save copy of AboutResources.txt from where you save it back to resources folder inside visual studio. visual studio and your project must be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Build Action of each of your images is set to AndroidAsset and not AndroidResource.

Steps:
1. Right click on the AboutResources.txt.
2. Goto Properties
3. Check the Build Action

Comment: After 3rd step?